# Turn rate of a jet vs. biplane

Tags: mechanical-engineering, aerospace-engineering, aerodynamics

A friend and I were debating whether a biplane/propeller plane has a faster turning rate than jet aircraft. I argued that the propeller planes often do have better turning rates than jets, but I could not explain why. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Did you think about the difference in stalling speeds...

Comment: This question might be a better fit for SE Aviation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A low speed biplane will have a smaller turn *radius* than a jet, for the same reason that a car can make a smaller radius turn at low speeds.

For "normal" non-aerobatic flight, the standard *time* to make a horizontal turns is the same for all aircraft: 3 degrees per second, or 2 minutes for a full 360 degree circle. If a jet is flying at 5 times the speed of a biplane, the radius of the circle will be 5 times as big.

Low speed aircraft may use a standard turn rate of 6 degrees per second not 3, and some very large aircraft use 1.5 degrees per second. Of course if air space is being shared by different aircraft, it is easier for air traffic control to avoid potential collisions if all the planes turn at the same rate.

The maximum rate of turn is limited by the centripetal acceleration of the plane. Sustained turns above about 5g are limited by the ability of the pilot to remain conscious, but partial turns up to 9g are possible. The maximum instantaneous turn rate for a military fast jet is typically about 20 degrees per second, which would theoretically give a 360 degree turn in 18 seconds if other factors didn't prevent that from being done.

As well as the inability of the pilot to operate at sustained high g loads, the drag on the aircraft increases at very high turn rates, and the engine power may not be able to maintain constant speed, even flying a military jet with reheat. If the speed reduces too much, there is a high probability that the intended turn will become a stall or a spin.

Of course the fastest "turn" in one sense of the word is an *intentional* spin. Aircraft designed for aerobatics may be able to spin faster than *one complete turn per second*.

Answer (score 0):

Long ago , the IL Air National Guard flew F51 and F84 ; at summer camp they shared the same dedicated airfield. In the distance you could see an F84 line up on a straight approach to land; Occasionally an F51 would make a 90 degree turn and land in front of the F84. When the F84 made its large turn it was so far away that you couldn't see it unless you were looking that way with binoculars. The F51 were dramatically more maneuverable than the F84 . I think it is a safe guess the a biplane is more maneuverable than an F51 , so no comparison to a modern jet. However , the speeds are rather different .

Answer (score 0):

Interesting Question:

(Information from my own knowledge as well as from [Aerodynamics for Naval Aviators](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/media/00-80t-80.pdf). I do feel like this question is better suited to the aerodynamics area.)

Formally, turn rate is defined as a unit of angular measurement over a unit of time; degrees per second is a common unit of turn rate. The other measure used to define turning performance is turn radius, otherwise explained as the size of a turn at a predefined speed and altitude.

Turn rate can be defined in many different ways: instantaneous, sustained, maximum, and a few others I've probably forgotten. Instantaneous turn rate regards performance if the pilot pulls as hard as possible on the stick without destroying the airplane: generally, planes lose speed at their instantaneous turn rates, as they use more energy in the turn than their engines can produce. Sustained turn rate, on the other hand, is the maximum rate of turn that can be achieved while maintaining a steady altitude. Sustained turn rate assumes that there is a speed at which the drag and engine power will become equal. Maximum turn rate is a term added to both instantaneous and sustained turn rate to, commonly, note that at a certain speed, a plane has the best rate (degrees per second) of turning. This is most often seen with sustained turn rate, because instantaneous turn rate generally increases with speed (but not always).

Generally, (theoretical) comparisons between low wing loaded airplanes (generally lighter, slower propeller planes) and high wing loaded airplanes (high speed jet aircraft) result in the jet aircraft being much faster, but with less of a turn rate. The general explanation behind this is that planes which fly at a lower speed are limited less by human endurance: G-forces increase proportionally to the flying speed and change in velocity during a turn. Slower planes can increase the change in velocity (pulling the turn tighter) because their speed is lower, if the G limits are the same.

In the sustained turn department, modern fighter jets tend to be faster than biplanes; in practical combat, it can be argued that biplanes use their low speeds and higher instantaneous turn rates to have long lasting duels that start at altitude and spiral towards the ground.

Theoretically, if you strap the engine from an F16 onto a biplane, and replace the human with a computer, the aircraft could turn 180 degrees in a couple of seconds.

Interesting question, but the issue in comparison can be the less efficient engines on biplane designs, and more efficient engines on modern aircraft.